# How to fill missing values of data in dataframe using other values in same column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
Name  Value
Car1  Station
Car1  NA
Car1  NA 
Car1  Station
Car2  Hatchback
Car2  NA
```

Now, I want to fill the `NA` values in the `Value` column with the non NA value of the same `Name` variable. So, the resulting dataframe should look like

```
Name  Value
Car1  Station
Car1  Station
Car1  Station 
Car1  Station
Car2  Hatchback
Car2  Hatchback
```

Does anyone know how to do it without looping through the entire dataframe?

Comment: very efficient solution with tidyr: df %>% group_by(Name) %>% fill(Value)